# QMysql Driver not loaded error

Tags: mysql, qt

When executing the following code I get an error that the Mysql driver is not loaded:

```
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("test");
    db.setUserName("test");
    db.setPassword("test");

    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"), db.lastError().text());
    } else
        qDebug() << "OPEN";
```

and in my .pro file I added it with

```
QT       += core gui sql
```

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and I have installed
libqt5sql5-mysql
libqt4-sql-mysql

and when locating them with I get

```
locate libqsql
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so
```

also when running the ldd command all dependencies can be found:

```
ldd libqsqlite.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff631e6000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f831f6d3000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f831f691000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f831f1d4000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f831ee52000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f831ea88000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f831e869000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f831e665000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f831e44b000)
    libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007f831dfe7000)
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f831dc53000)
    libpcre16.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 (0x00007f831d9f0000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f831d6e0000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f831d4d8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f831d1d0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f831cfb8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557933e71000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f831b501000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f831b293000)
```

When executing the code I get as output:

```
  QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
  QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Possible, you need to compile `qmysql` with your version of `libmysql`. It is known issue.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: You're missing the `libsqlmysql.so` for Qt5, you probably should [compile them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6494435/1771479).

Comment: What do you mean with compile them?? In qtCreator I already rebuild and executed qmake...

Comment: You may use google to find information, how to compile Qt plugins.

Comment: Try this: http://seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows

Comment: I'm running it on Linux!?

Comment: Did your tried @peppe answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369480/qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-on-ubuntu-15-04-64bits?