# QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded on Ubuntu 15.04 64bits

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5.6

In Ubuntu 15.04 64 bits I installed Qt5.6 (online installer) and while trying to move my development environment from Windows 7 to Linux I faced the following:

```
SqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667768/qmysql-driver-available-but-not-loaded), I managed to find  `~/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so` and then:

```
$ ldd libqsqlmysql.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffd571000)
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe94ef24000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fe94ecec000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fe94ead2000)
    libssl.so.10 => not found
    libcrypto.so.10 => not found
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/user/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007fe94e88d000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/user/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fe94e17a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe94df5c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe94dc4d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe94d944000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe94d72e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe94d364000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /home/user/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007fe94cec9000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /home/user/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007fe94cb11000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /home/user/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007fe94b12e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe94af29000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe94ad27000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe94ab1f000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe94a80f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056024837f000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fe94a5a2000)
```

Tells `libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found`. In fact, it seems I have a newer version:

```
find / -name libmysqlclient_r*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.1.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.a
```

Perhaps that's the problem. Could some one confirm? How should I proceed?

Comment: That's must most likely the problem, yes. Note that it reports libssl and libcrypto as missing, too. If your distro doesn't offer the mysqlclient in that version, you need to compile the mysql plugin yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, double check that you have the packages containing `libssl.so`, `libcrypto.so` and `libmysqlclient_r.so` installed (looks like you have this last one, it's extremely likely you also have the first two, but just double check).

Then, your problem is that you have those shared objects with a different SONAME, sign that they're binary incompatible with the plugin shipped with Qt, which therefore needs to be recompiled.

Therefore:

1. install the *development versions* of the packages found above (`libssl-dev`, `mysql-client-dev` or similar).
2. run the `MaintenanceTool` from your Qt installation, and be sure to select to install Qt's *source code* too.
3. Go in `QTDIR/5.6/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/`.
4. Run the *right* `qmake`, i.e. the one coming from that installation of Qt (not the system wide one or similar). Best way to be sure is providing the full path to it: `QTDIR/5.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake`.
5. Run `make`. Hopefully this will just work™; if it complains about some missing libraries, install them and rerun `make`.
6. This should now have produced a new `libqsqlmysql.so` plugin; overwrite the old one with this new one.

Comment: This did not "just work™" for me. What I had to do was steps 1 through 4, then edit Makefile and replace all occurances of "-std=c++1z" to "-std=c++11". The reason is that this was built on RHEL and I am on Ubuntu and the respective gcc suopport different -std= flags.

Comment: May I ask, what Qt version was that? In theory qmake should've picked the same flags used when compiling Qt itself. (Smelling like a bug)

Comment: Its latest & greatest 5.8 :)

Comment: Oh,  Ubuntu version is 16.04 amd64 with gcc 4.9.3

Comment: Aaaand,  finally a comment .  Why build on RHEL when 90% of end users are on Ubuntu?

Comment: But doesn't Ubuntu 16.04 ship with GCC 5.4.0? The "build on an old RHEL" story is to try to get maximum compatibility across the various Linux distributions. Otherwise you'd get a Qt which is not installable on anything but the latest releases (and, yes, there are still people running ancient stuff...). Where did you get the 90% number from?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 and compiling my project using system's Qt5. The driver is successfully loaded after I install `libqt5sql5-mysql` package.

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two fixes for this issue. First try and locate the qtbase folder located within your qt directory and try run ./configure -plugin-sql-mysql which will activate the driver if they're missing.

If this doesn't solve your issue, I suggest that you double check your code and try running one of the Qt examples which makes a connection to the Sql databases. I.e. modify the example code which connects to a local SQLite database changing the parameter to MySQL. If this example doesn't throw 'Driver not loaded error' then follow the step below.

Make sure you're using the static function of the QSqlDatabase i.e. rather than using

```
QSqlDatabase *db = new QSqlDatabase(); 
db->addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

you should be doing

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

Comment: I'm curious about the diff between the two ways ("static function of the QSqlDatabase")?

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem with `Qt5.11.1` and my OS is `Ubuntu16.04` and I have resolve the problem by installing `libmysqlclient18` from here

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libmysqlclient18/5.6.25-0ubuntu1

After download run the command from download directory,

`sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient18_5.6.25-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Thanks this works fine for me on ubutnu 16.04.3 and Qt5.9.3

Answer (score 0):

For use MySql with PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi, it's fine to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve MYSQL driver not loaded and if you don't have MYSQL driver available with your Qt install:

#### First and foremost:

try install `libqt5sql5-mysql`, this is the easiest way.

`$ sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql`

If the issue still persists, then maybe you have installed Qt from source and didn't config it with MySQL driver. You have to build and install the driver yourself. Here is how to do it:

> These following commands run in my VM: ubuntu20.04 with Qt5.14.0 installed

###### 1. install dependency

`$ sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`

###### 2. locate your Qt path.

It looks like `Qt[version]/[version]/` and inside it will have a folder `Src` and `gcc_64`. Save this path to shell variable `qtpath`, for example, mine is:

`$ qtpath=/opt/Qt5.14.0/5.14.0`

###### 3. Make && make install mysql driver (use `sudo` if neccessary):

```
$ cd $qtpath/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers 
$ sudo $qtpath/gcc_64/bin/qmake sqldrivers.pro 
$ sudo make 
$ sudo make install
```

After this, you will have a Sql driver built and installed with your version of Qt. However, if you have **"ERROR: You cannot configure sqldrivers separately within a top-level build.”** this means you have already run the `configure` script before. To resolve this, run:

```
$ cd $qtpath/Src
$ sudo ./configure -sql-mysql MYSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/mysql MYSQL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

If it success, you will have `MySQL......Yes` in the config note. Then run step 3 above again to build and install only the MySQL driver.