# how to connecte My Application Qt cMake to Mysql DATABASE

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, cmake, cmakelists-options

I'm working under Qt widget Project using qmake , here every thing going will .
now i want to switch to  cMake ,  i don't know how   i can connect My Application to Mysql under cMake
after a long search in the internet i still not found a solution for my problem
her My approach
i added this lines to My cMakeLists.txt

> "find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Sql REQUIRED)
> target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Qt6::Sql)"

add this line to my header file

> #include QSqlDatabase

i created a simple teste function like this

```
 void MainWindow::testDatabaseinCMake()
 {

     QSqlDatabase dataBase;
     // here you are Data Base Parameters
   dataBase= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
   dataBase.setHostName("127.0.0.1"); // @ip MySql Server
   dataBase.setDatabaseName("mecaniquecalculation"); //Database Name
   dataBase.setUserName("root"); // User Name
   dataBase.setPassword("rrrrr)I"); // Password
   dataBase.setPort(3306);
   
 }
```

but i still obtain many errors like this
QSqlDatabase file not found
my be someone can Helpe me
thank you in advance

Comment: in can't understand your queszion. Cmake is a tool that uses a script to compile a programm or library, so why doy you want to switch to cmake and what you try to achieve

Comment: @nbk , thank you for your answer ,https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-and-cmake-the-past-the-present-and-the-future

Comment: for many reason i want to switch in to cMake  ,  and now i want to connect to Mysql database  with my application but i don't found helpe , how i can do it when we use cMake

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590552/qt-cmake-finds-mysql-but-it-does-not-compile-it here is a functioning cmake script of cpurse see also the comment what os needed., maybe this helps you

Comment: thank you for your help, here they use  ubuntu like OS,  I'm using windows OS , i'm not found yet solution

Comment: such information belongs to the question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483523/qt-how-to-getcompile-mysql-driver

Comment: Incredible, i feel i'm the first one using MySQL in Qt cMake

Comment: Check the official docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtsql-index.html. You need to 1) find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Sql) 2) target_link_libraries(<ProjectNAme> PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Sql). After these changes, CMAKE should pick up the SQL capabilities.. it compiles fine for me on Qt6.

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Sql)
```

before this code

```
if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(appName MANUAL_FINALIZATION ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(appName SHARED ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
    else()
        add_executable(appName ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
    endif()
endif()
```

and then add

```
target_link_libraries(appName PRIVATE Qt6::Sql)
```